# I want to show this Image on my widget level and onclick should play in full screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

I want to show something like on my flutter widget if the url is video

[image]

and onClick he show start playing the video in full screen

Answer (score 0):

You should use "video_player" and "chewie"

video_player= "https://pub.dev/packages/video_player"
chewie ="https://pub.dev/packages/chewie"

Comment: this two is given me headache... the video is not showing